# Problema com session_set_save_handler

Tags: php, mysql, session

Estou usando o `session_set_save_handler` para gravar a sessão no MySQL, porém um erro vem me atormentando.

Quando faço login no IE com um usuário, depois fecho o navegador sem dar `logout` e entro no Chrome, eu já inicio a sessão logado com o usuário do IE. Ou seja, ele está me logando automaticamente com a sessão de outro usuário.

Segue minha função:

```
 <?php

GLOBAL $mysqli_link;

function _open($save_path, $session_name) {
    return true;
}

function _close() {
    return true;
}

function _read($id) {
    GLOBAL $mysqli_link;

    $id = hash('sha512', $id);

    $stmt = $mysqli_link->prepare("SELECT data FROM session WHERE  id = ? limit 1");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $num = $result->num_rows;

    if ($num>0) {
        $record = $result->fetch_assoc();
        return $record['data'];
    }
    else{
        return '';
    }
}

function _write($id, $data) {
    GLOBAL $mysqli_link;

    //echo session_id();

    $id = hash('sha512', $id);

    $access = time();

    if($data!=""){
        $stmt = $mysqli_link->prepare("REPLACE INTO session VALUES (?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $id, $access, $data);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    return true;
}

function _destroy($id) {
    GLOBAL $mysqli_link;

    $id = hash('sha512', $id);

    $stmt = $mysqli_link->prepare("DELETE FROM session WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
}

function _clean($max) {
    GLOBAL $mysqli_link;
    $CurrentTime = time();

    //$old = time() - $max;
    //$stmt = $mysqli_link->prepare("DELETE FROM session WHERE access < ?");

    $stmt = $mysqli_link->prepare("DELETE FROM session WHERE access + ? < ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $max, $CurrentTime);
    $stmt->execute();
}

session_set_save_handler('_open','_close','_read','_write','_destroy','_clean');
register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');



?>
```

----------------------------------------> EDITADO

na pagina index.php tenho isso:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["user"])){
 $user = $_SESSION["user"];
 header("Location:welcome.php");
 die();
}
```

a intenção aqui é verificar se a pessoa esta logada, se sim, envia para página welcome.php.

e no welcome tenho isso para verificar se o usuario esta realmente logado para continuar na página:

```
session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION["id"]) || empty($_SESSION["user"]))
{
    header("Location:login.php");
    die();
}
```

Comment: Boa noite, o seu código só apresenta uma parte, é provavel que se houver uma falha de lógica, ela está aonde você iniciou o `session_start` e as outras funções que começam com `session_`. Se puder informe isto para ser possivel detectar o problema.

Comment: olá @GuilhermeNascimento! editei o código com a parte das sessões, será que estou fazendo algo errado nelas?

Comment: Então o `session_start` está correto, me diz uma coisa, o que o `$save_path` e o `$sessin_name` retornam em `function _open($save_path, $session_name) {`? Em ambos browsers? Vou tentar reproduzir o código, mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: muito obrigada @GuilhermeNascimento! hoje acabei descobrindo o erro, era simplesmente o "i" no bind param do select da função _read. a sessão passa uma variavel com letras e numeros. colocando o "i" em vez do "s" ela transformava a string em numero e ia pegando dados de outra sessão... enfim, um rolo por causa de um "i" em vez do "s".  muito obrigada pela ajuda novamente!!!

Comment: Qual foi a intenção aqui? `DELETE FROM session WHERE access + ? < ?`

Answer (score 0):

Posso ariscar e dizer que o problema é o `Replace Into` utilizado no seu código.

Modifique para:

```
if (empty($data)) {
    $stmt = $mysqli_link->prepare("INSERT INTO session VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $id, $access, $data);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Isso foi só um exemplo rápido. Porém o ideal seria verificar se existe alguma linha na tabela com esse id. Se existir, você atualize; se não, você insere.